# How to call a function defined in JSR223 Sampler in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have the function defined in JSR223 sampler in Jmeter.
I would like to call it in the different sampler in the same thread.

This function is create a new time value.

Thanks,

Pdo

Comment: Please show us what's defined, and the test plan.

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 options:

1. Switch from JSR223 Sampler to [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler). In that case you will be able to use [bsh.shared](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_variables) namespace to reuse variables, properties, and functions.
2. If your request can be narrowed down to creating a new time value there is [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function capable of returning current date in different formats. If you need time in the future/past - you can combine it with [__longSum](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__longSum) function. For better information on aforementioned and other functions refer to [How to Use JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series